# How to avoid the infinity loop on a class component reatc js?

Tags: reactjs, class

I used to use the hook, but i have to deal with a class component to open my modal.

I wanna switch my state show with a condition

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      restaurantName: "",
      isLoading: false,
      data: {},
      pourboireGeneral: false,
      tabServeur: [],
      show: false,
      email: "",
    };
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
  }

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
    console.log("this", this.state.show);
  };
```

i wanna switched my show with this function inside my class

```
  modalReferent = () => {
    if (
      this.state.pourboireGeneral === true &&
      this.state.tabServeur.length === 0
    ) {
      return this.setState({ show: true });
    } else {
      return this.setState({ show: false });
    }
  };
```

then my modal inside my render

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="homepage">
        <Row className="rowGlobal">
          <Col md={10}>
            <Personnel className="personnel" />

            <h1 className="titleQR">Mes QR Codes</h1>

            <Row className="rowGlobal">
              <Col md={{ span: 9, offset: 7 }} className="colTuto">
                <Modal
                  show={this.state.show}
                  onHide={false}
                  animation={true}
                  backdrop={true}
                  keyboard={false}
                  style={{ overlay: { zIndex: 3 } }}>
                  <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Désigner votre référent</Modal.Title>
                  </Modal.Header>
                  <Modal.Body>
                    <Row className="affiPop">
                      <Col s={12} md={12}>
                        <p>
                          Vous devez désigner un référent en rentrant son
                          adresse mail ci-dessous. Si vous n'avez pas d'autre
                          référent merci de rentrer votre adresse email et de
                          vous créer un compte bénéficiaire.
                        </p>
                      </Col>
                      <Col>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="email"
                          onChange={this.handleInput}
                          placeholder="Bénéficiaire"
                          className="inputAffi"
                        />
                        <input
                          type="submit"
                          value="Envoyer la demande"
                          onClick={this.addAffiliation}
                          className="button"
                        />
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
```

When i do it like that, i have an error saying to me
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

i really struggled to find the good way to change my state with class component

Comment: invert the logic rather hardcoding it `return this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });`

Comment: on my componentdidmount